# Glide is loading half image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-glide

When I try to load image with I get this result:

[image: Result]

This is my simple code:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.girl_with_coffee_and_phone)
                .placeholder(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .into(mBackgroundImage);
```

This is my activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Logs:

```
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7842bfdc00 (InsetDrawable) with handle 0x783169e820
```

Comment: check your log it might be printing some error

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/700 will help you

Comment: Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.girl_with_coffee_and_phone)
    .override(640,960)
                .placeholder(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .into(mBackgroundImage);

Comment: try software rendring for imageview `mBackgroundImage.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Comment: as mentioned on https://github.com/bumptech/glide

**Huge Images** (maps, comic strips): **Glide can load huge images** by downsampling them, but does not support zooming and panning ImageViews as they require special resource optimizations (such as tiling) to work without OutOfMemoryErrors.

Comment: The problem is that some of the images are well displayed and some not. (they are in the same resolution) Resolution is 1000 x 500

Comment: @user2299040 override didn't fixed. Askhay Bhat setLayerType also.

Comment: @Nominalista can you provide the image? let me test

Comment: @Nominalista You should use `override(width ,height)` for `Glide` which will resize your image which you want.

Comment: got the same problem.I think the problem is inside glide. check it https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/391

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.girl_with_coffee_and_phone)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(mBackgroundImage);
```

remove the android:scaleType param from the xml file.

and in the activity you will have:

```
ImageView mBackgroundImage= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_background);
```

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: is it the image cut in half or the image view holding it?

Comment: Image is cut in half.

Comment: have u tried it with out glide,  mBackgroundImage.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.girl_with_coffee_and_phone)

Answer (score -1):

I check the source and found an workaround solution, just check my project in [github](https://github.com/vince-styling/glide370android)

Comment: This does not explain anything about how you fixed the problem. "Look though all of the code in this Github project" is not useful.