# Glide sometimes show half image

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I am using glide in my app to show images. Images come from amazon s3 and load in image view. But sometimes glide just load some portion of image. I am using its cache strategy. When i set cache to false then image load each and every time. That will cost a lot of data to user. So i think thats not a good option. Below is my code and image of problem.

[image]

Glide code:

```
Glide.with(context).load(posts.get(position).getFile()).placeholder(R.drawable.qurbani_background_6).error(R.drawable.error_image)
                    .fitCenter().listener(new RequestListener<File, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //Toast.makeText(context , e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //HomeActivity h = new HomeActivity();
                    //h.galleryTask();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            }).into(holder.postImage);
```

And amazon s3 download listener code:

```
public void transferObserverListener(final TransferObserver transferObserver)
    {
        transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener(){

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state)
            {
                Log.e("statechange", state+"");
                if(state.toString() == "COMPLETED")
                {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal)
            {
                int percentage = 0;
                if(bytesTotal != 0)
                {
                    percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
                }
                Log.e("percentage",percentage +"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex)
            {
                p.dismiss();
                Log.e("error",ex.toString());
            }

        });
    }
```

I am using recycler view. Image should load in full view.Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: possible dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524604/glide-is-loading-half-image

Comment: yeah ihave seen that.... but there is no solution .... :P

Answer (score 1):

I used `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1`

```
try {
                        RequestOptions requestOption =
                                new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.box).
                                        error(R.drawable.box)
                                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);


                            Glide.with(context).load(assetComponentModel.getUrl())
                                    .apply(requestOption)
                                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                                            mHolder.assets_image.setImageDrawable(resource);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                                            mHolder.assets_image.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                            mHolder.assets_image.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onLoadStarted(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                                            mHolder.assets_image.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                                        }
                                    });
                        } 

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

and used  `rclOfferListView.setItemViewCacheSize(list.size());`

used destroy code in your fragment

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        if (rclOfferListView != null)
            rclOfferListView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Results : image show only one time. no any half images.

Comment: rclOfferlistview.setItemViewcacheSize(list.size()) whats its doing ?

Comment: Recycle view store visible item in catch , if you again come same item then recycle view show store view rather then new create view.  but you need clear catch during  destroy fragment . i have updated code.

Comment: Above code taking from my running app . i don't know what is problem in your code.  we used 'setImageDrawable' for set image as set normal image so,why you are facing half images problem. may be some other problem